# Accessing variable input in A.cs in B.cs

Tags: c#, input, textbox

I need to use a variable obtained from an input in textBox1 in A.cs, in B.cs. The variable is in a method in a class of A.cs. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to set the value as an instance variable and expose to classB trough a getter function.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable in A.cs class eg:-

```
string _username;

public string USERNAME
        {
            get { return _username; }
            set { _username= value; }
        }
```

After that Create A.cs class Object and initialise UserName variable where u have textBox1 control eg:-

```
A a = new A();
a.USERNAME=textBox1.Text;
```

Now, u can access textBox1 value in A.cs class

Comment: Where is B.cs used then?

Comment: Repeat A.cs code in B.cs and access B.cs members throw its object and initialise  B.cs variable like A.cs